# Type error not coming in compile time, not able to make my method type safe in Typescript code

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to typescript my code is not showing compile error if passing the wrong type to parameter of method. My code is something like this:-

```
export interface empData {
   empName:string;
}
export class Employee implements empData
{
empName:string;
constructor(empName:string){
this.empName=empName;
}
```

> Now I want to use the Employee class as the datatype for that I
>   created one function in separate file and write method as:-

```
export function showName(empName:Employee){
return empName;
}
```

> Now in my component I am passing showName as props using redux and
>   connect method

```
export default class EmployeeDetail extends React.Component{
//now I am trying to call the function
showEmp(){
this.props.showName('');
} 
}
```

> **this.props.showName(' ')** this call not showing any type error, ideally
>   it should pass as **this.props.showName(new
>   Employee({empName='someName'});** Please assist me What I am doing
>   mistake. How can I make my code typesafe.In above example I want the
>   method parameter should be type safe by the Employee object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`React.Component` is generic, it's first generic parameter is the type of `props`. You can use an anonymous interface, or a named interface as a parameter, and this will trigger the compiler to perform the apropriate checks:

```
 class EmployeeDetail extends React.Component<{ showName: (empName: Employee) => Employee}> {
    //now I am trying to call the function
    showEmp() {
        this.props.showName(''); //error
    }
}

//OR 
interface EmployeeDetailProps { showName: (empName: Employee) => Employee}
class EmployeeDetail extends React.Component<EmployeeDetailProps> {
    //now I am trying to call the function
    showEmp() {
        this.props.showName(''); //error
    }
}

// Usage
let d = <EmployeeDetail showName={showName} />
```

Comment: It is working, I was doing the same thing but I was using empName?:string because of this it was not throwing error if I was passing other type.